# Make the initial dropdown menu option in Concrete5 not go to a page

Tags: concrete5

I am building a website using Concrete5 that includes a drop down navigation using the Auto Nav.

Right now the navigation looks like this:

```
--Home 
--Schools 
   --School 1
   --School 2
   --School 3
```

Right now when you click on Schools it takes you to a page (which is blank because I haven't added anything)

My question is, how would you make it so Schools didn't go anywhere when clicked and you had to choose from the drop down options?

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround to make a "dummy" parent page in a Concrete5 Nav: use an External Link for the main Schools page instead of an actual Concrete5 page.

1. **Create** a new **External Link** in the Site Map under **Home** titled, "Schools".
   For the link, enter a `#` *(pound sign, with no http://)*, or
   `javascript(0);`
2. **Move** all the pages currently inside the existing "Schools" page to be under the new "Schools" (do this by dragging-and-dropping each School onto the new external link
3. **Delete** the old "Schools" parent page.

Another more in-depth option includes creating a custom page attribute called something like "nav_link_dummy", then using a custom AutoNav template to check (in the PHP script) for that attribute to not show the link. Use:

```
`if $_c->getCollectionAttributeValue('nav_link_dummy')`
```

to check for the attribute in the AutoNav template.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy fix for this, do not use dpidan's work around.

Go to Page Attributes and add one called 'nav_target' of type Text

On the properties of 'Schools' add that attribute and enter # as the target or javascript(0);

No need to use a hack when functionality exists in Concrete5 http://legacy-documentation.concrete5.org/editors/dashboard/pages-and-themes/attributes/built-in-attributes